# If $f$ is holomorphic on the closed unit disc, prove $\int_Cf(z)\log(z)dz=2\pi i\int_0^1f(x)dx$ where $C$ is the unit circle.

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

> If $f$ is holomorphic on the closed unit disc, prove $\int_Cf(z)\log(z)dz=2\pi i\int_0^1f(x)dx$ where $C$ is the unit circle.

Hint is to use integration by part but I can't find a good reference for how to apply that to counter integrals. My first guess would be direct evaluation but I can't get the $\log$ to go away, and likewise with any approach involving Taylor expanding $f(z)$ at $0$. Please give hints not direct solutions.

Comment: The usual integration by parts is available if you use parametrization for contour integral.

Comment: As Riemann said, you can use the standard way to parametrize unit circle $t\mapsto e^{it}$. What I would then add as a hint is to think of $\frac{d}{dt} (F(e^{it}))$ where $F$ is antiderivative of $f$. @Riemann, you can easily rework your deleted answer to consist of hints instead of the full answer.

Comment: You did not specify the branch of $\log z$.

Comment: Choosing $\log(e^{i\theta}) = i\theta$ for $\theta$ from $0$ to $2\pi$, I do not get this answer.  So it depends on the branch of the logarithm.

Comment: @GEdgar, if I'm not mistaken, choosing $f$ to be constantly $1$, you get $2\pi i e^{-ix}$ where branch cut is chosen in direction of angle $x$.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to apply Cauchy's theorem to the loop $\gamma = \gamma_1 \cup \gamma_2 \cup \gamma_3 \cup \gamma_4$, where:

- $\gamma_1$ is an arc on the unit circle $C$, going anticlockwise from $\sqrt{1 - \epsilon^2}+i\epsilon$ to $\sqrt{1 - \epsilon^2}-i\epsilon$.
- $\gamma_2$ is the straight line segment, going from $\sqrt{1 - \epsilon^2}-i\epsilon$ to $-i\epsilon$
- $\gamma_3$ is an arc on the circle centred at $0$ with radius $\epsilon$, going clockwise from $-i\epsilon$ to $+i\epsilon$.
- $\gamma_4$ is the straight line segment, going from $+i\epsilon$ to $\sqrt{1 - \epsilon^2}+i\epsilon$.

Cauchy's theorem tells us that $\int_\gamma f(z) \log(z) dz = 0$.

(I'm assuming that the branch cut for $\log(z)$ runs along the positive real axis.)

Now consider the limit $\epsilon \to 0$.

- Argue that $\int_{\gamma_1} f(z) \log(z) dz \to \int_C f(z) \log(z)$ in this limit.
- Argue that $\int_{\gamma_3} f(z) \log(z) dz \to 0$ in this limit.
- Argue that $\int_{\gamma_2} f(z) \log(z) dz + \int_{\gamma_4} f(z) \log(z) dz \to - 2\pi i \int_0^1 f(x) dx$ in this limit.

In the third bullet point, the intuition is that fact that $\log(x + i\epsilon) \to  \log(x)$ as $\epsilon$ tends to zero from above, but $\log(x - i\epsilon) \to  \log(x) + 2\pi i$ as $\epsilon$ tends to zero from above.

It's quite possible that you'll have to amend some of the details as you work through this. However, I'm confident that the overall approach should work.

**Edit:** I thought a little how one might take these limits rigorously. It seems like the argument might be easier if we introduce *two* small parameters:

- $r$, the radius of the small circle that $\gamma_3$ wraps around
- $\epsilon$, the vertical separation between $\gamma_2$ and $\gamma_4$.

I'd be inclined to take the $\epsilon \to 0$ limit first, and *then* take the $r \to 0$ limit.

---

**Another approach**

Here's another approach, based on FShrike's answer, which has been deleted for some reason. @FShrike - if you undelete your answer, I'll upvote.

Since $f$ is holomorphic on a domain containing the closed unit disk, $f$ has an antiderivative $F$ on the closed unit disk.

Let $\gamma_1$ be the same arc as above as in my first approach. Let $a_\epsilon = \sqrt{1 - \epsilon^2} + i\epsilon$ and $b_\epsilon = \sqrt{1 - \epsilon^2} - i\epsilon$ be the endpoints of this arc.

We have
$$ \int_{\gamma_1} \frac d {dz}(F(z) \log(z)) dz = F(b_\epsilon) \log(b_\epsilon) - F(a_\epsilon) \log(a_\epsilon)$$

Applying the chain rule, we also have
$$ \int_{\gamma_1} \frac d {dz}(F(z) \log(z)) dz = \int_{\gamma_1} f(z) \log(z) dz + \int_{\gamma_1} \frac{F(z)}{z} dz $$

The next step is to take the limit $\epsilon \to 0$ in both of the expressions above, to show that
$$ \oint_C f(z) \log(z) dz = 2\pi i (F(1) - F(0)).$$

Finally, show that if $\gamma'$ is any path between $0$ and $1$, then $ F(1) - F(0) = \int_{\gamma'} f(z) dz$. You can derive the result you want by taking a particular choice for $\gamma'$.

I think this method is what is meant by the hint about "integrating by parts". Notice that we've effectively integrated by parts, without using an explicit parametrisation for $\gamma_1$. Which is nice.

Comment: $\gamma_1$ avoids the positive real axis. $\gamma_1$ goes anticlockwise.

Comment: Ahhhh my apologies my mental picture of the contour was wrong

Comment: By the way, I wrote this purely based on intuition. I haven't worked through the details of the taking the limits rigorously. If you work through this and find that my approach doesn't work, then please leave a comment and I'll look at this again.

Comment: No, +1, I agree with it. The details seem fairly standard and I’ve ‘checked’ them (as much as you can without pen and paper). Nice approach

Comment: FShrike's answer was deleted because OP wrote: "Please give hints not direct solutions." You can see there are two deleted answers for the same reason.